# What determines the name of the response object in a JQuery AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In the following Jquery AJAX function (and response event)

```
request = $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: loginCredentials,
            dataType: "json"
        });

request.done(function(responseObject){
    //use this wonderful information
}
```

I'm confused about where the response object (I magically named this `responseObject`) gets its name? In some examples I see it named `msg` but in other places, I see different names. Where is it defined? By JQuery? By the server that sends this response?

Is there some parameter in the ajax function that I can choose how I name the object?

Comment: you're defining it when you define the function. it's just a function parameter

Answer (score 1):

It's defined by you. You pass a function to done, done calls that function and passes a parameter, something like:

```
function doStuff(aCallback) {
    var x = 1;
    callback(x);
}

doStuff(function(herpDerp) {
    console.log(herpDerp);
});
```

Typically, the documentation will indicate what it will pass to your callback function, however what you call those variables inside your function doesn't matter.

The docs for done:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

`jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});`

So the docs say the first thing passed to your callback is the data from the response. You can call that whatever you like, but it's the data.

Comment: It matters. I don't know what it is that I'm naming it, and have not yet been able to access my response. Could you use the example I provided? (or elaborate a bit)

Comment: No, the name doesn't matter at all. Linked to the relevant docs.

Comment: Ok, still very confused. Let's restart. I'm a javascript beginner, it's nice to meet you, sir javascript pro. I'm trying to figure out where I can access the response to my AJAX request.

Comment: It says in the docs, the first thing it passes to done is `data`. If `data` is null or undefined, then your problem lies elsewhere and you haven't provided enough information.

Comment: I'm trying to get what you're saying, I am, and I really appreciate your help. I just did not see the answer to my question in your answer. Which I'm sure is my fault.

Comment: Ok. So `data` holds my response?

Comment: @jt0dd Yes, it's your response. Try a `console.log(data)` or `console.log(responseObject)` (to match your function).